# Multiple if conditionals

Tags: jquery

New to the world of jquery, How would I group these if conditional statements together? or any conditional statements in that case. 
Trying run this function all at once without making 5 different function that essentially do the same exact thing.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var menu = $('#site-nav');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;
    var locateHobby = $('#load-hobby');
    var hobbyLocateOrigOffsetY = locateHobby.offset().top;
    var locateForm = $('#load-form');
    var formLocateOrigOffsetY = locateForm.offset().top;
    function scroll() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) && $(document.scrollTop() >= hobbyLocateOrigOffsetY) && $(document).scrollTop() >= formLocateOrigOffsetY)) {

            $('#site-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('.main-content').addClass('menu-padding');

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('#hob-slide').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
            }, 200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $('.wpcf7-form').addClass('animated slideInUp');
            }, 200);

        } else {
            $('#site-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('.main-content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }
}); //End no conflict
```

Comment: I didnt know that you can jquery like this. I thought that for some reason that you had to ALWAYS create a variable, and always create a function. I legit had 5-6 functions kinda doing the same thing(waiting for the scroll). And yes the variables were getting outta hand. Also where is the closing ")" for the first if statement in the code located? This was one of the things that got me as well. But great response tho! :-) @WilliamGates

Comment: The ) occurs the last .top. If you use an editor like notepad++ it will show you open/closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clarify what you are trying to simplify; I am guessing you want to perform the if statement without the need to create a bunch of variables. If that is the case you can simplify the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scroll() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#site-nav').offset().top &&
            $(document).scrollTop() >= $('#load-hobby').offset().top &&
            $(document).scrollTop() >= $('#load-form').offset().top) {

            $('#site-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('.main-content').addClass('menu-padding');

            setTimeout(function() {
             $('#hob-slide').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
            }, 200);

            setTimeout(function() {
             $('.wpcf7-form').addClass('animated slideInUp');
            }, 200);

        } else {
            $('#site-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('.main-content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }
}); //End no conflict
```

Comment: Do not assume. Clarify from OP and then answer.

Comment: okay cool. I think this will work... So could I just keep adding coditional statement up top then do the actual actions below? Looks like exactly what you did

Comment: and also is it best to call this on document or on the window? I've heard both but want like the best practice.

Comment: Yes you can chain conditions in the same if as many as you want. 
Document is what you want to use. Personally I normally use the short hard $(function(){}) instead of $(document).ready(function(){}). See https://api.jquery.com/ready/